# Access Count of Rows Where Field is not Null

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, count

I need to count rows where the value of Master.[Date BP] is not Null - any ideas how I would do this?

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
SELECT Master.[Date BP], Count(Master.[Date BP]) AS CountOfField,
FROM Master
GROUP BY Master.[Date BP];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Count([Date BP]) AS CountOfField
FROM Master
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `count` is the right idea. You just need to remove the `group by` clause, as you want a single answer. Additionally, you have a redundant comma at the end of the select list:

```
SELECT Count(Master.[Date BP]) AS CountOfField
FROM   Master
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are correct. Just in case you may face other problems with other aggregate functions, aggregate functions in SQL will ignore the null value.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx